# How to secure an external page that is included in a menu page of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, security

I have created a theme options page for my WordPress theme with the following code in functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_options_page' );

function register_options_page()
{
    $my_hook = add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'merry_options', 'get_theme_options', 'dashicons-share-alt', 99 );
    // var_dump($my_hook); die();
}

function get_theme_options()
{  
    include_once get_template_directory()."/framework/themeoptions.php";
}
```

As you can see, it includes an external page located at .../framework/themeoptions.php. Now the problem is anyone can go and open that URL to access this page directly. I want that page only to accessed when the WordPress admin is signed in. Can you tell me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following function:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
     echo "You are viewing the WordPress Administration Panels";
} else {
     echo "You are viewing the theme";
}
```

as the right way to check for administrator privileges.

You can read more about this function in the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way. I can use

```
<?php if (current_user_can('administrator')) { }?>
```

to see if WordPress admin is accessing the page. Is there a better approach?